# What `git push` does under the hood?

Tags: git

So I have just learned that `git pull` does several things

1. `fetch` to update local remote mirror
2. `merge` to merge local branch with updated local remote mirror

But what about `push` does it do several things under the hood similar to `pull` ?

Answer (score 6):

Not really.

In a very technical sense, yes, it does multiple things, but unlike `pull` (where you might reasonably do `fetch` and `merge` as two different actions) all of the stuff that `push` does is generally always done together:

1. Pack up the set of commits that isn't on the remote host
2. Send the packed commits to the remote host
3. Update the remote ref to point at the commit you pushed to it

Doing #3 wouldn't really make sense without also doing #1 and #2 - and doing #1 and #2 wouldn't really do anything without also doing #3.

`push` never merges - you either overwrite the remote ref or your push fails.

Comment: It effectively does a `git merge --ff-only` to update the remote reference.

Comment: @Zeeker which isn't really a merge (just a `branch --contains` check).

Answer (score 0):

You can reed the official documentation of git at
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push
There you can see, that

> git push

does not do several things step by step